# having more then one value but getting a keyerror with python,pandas and excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i trying to have python look at the excel sheet and look for on row 1 and look for SN, Unit_serial_number, and serial_number but every time i have it look for it. it does not go on to the elif and gives me a error but it works fine if you just have SN though. when they put the dataform it does not know the info about the excel file at all. just not sure how to fix the issue.

```
#droping the file you want to take the sn and
try:
    droppedFile = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print("no file dropped")
    exit()

df = pd.read_excel(droppedFile)

#checking if these are real.

if "SN" in df.loc[0:, ["SN"]]:
    print(df.loc[0:, ["SN"]])

#this checks if there is any Unit_serial_number in the excel file.
elif 'Unit_Serial_Number' in df.loc[0:, ['Unit_Serial_Number']]:
    print(df.loc[0:, ['Unit_Serial_Number']])

#this checks if there is any Serial_Number in the excel file.
elif 'Serial_Number' in df.loc[0:, ['Serial_Number']]:
    print(df.loc[0:, ['Serial_Number']])
#this just lets you know that all the value you put in are not there and this will end the code.
else:
    print("there is no Serial_number in this excel or nothing at all\n")
    exit()
```

error code

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['SN'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Without knowing what your dataframe is looking like, I think it will be hard to give an answer...

Comment: would there be a way just have it skip that if statement so it does not give out the error?

Comment: is there a way to make a dataform from pulling it from the excel sheet?

Comment: Well, you are creating a dataframe... `df = pd.read_excel(droppedFile)`   [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: am i making the dataframe wrong for this?

Comment: Not that i know of, but we don't know what is it looking like (we don't know the content of the excel file, and how does it endup in your dataframe.) Maybe you could include it in your question ?

Comment: Also, Check if the column name has spaces.

Comment: i check that out @ManjunathKMayya